# Error inflating class Fragment, when adding navGraph attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-navigation-graph

I know there are a few questions and answers about this problem, but none of the solutions fixed my problem. I get an

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

error, when I add the navGraph attribute with the navigation xml-file.

---

So here is my activity_login.xml (with the fragment container):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<fragment
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:id="@+id/loginFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

The nav_graph.xml is just as empty as it is generated.

---

Here are the important dependencies for the fragment:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
```

When I do not include this line *app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"* in my activity_login.xml -layout, I do **not** get an error. What's my mistake?

I am using *Android Studio 4.1 Canary 10*

Please just ask if I need to share more code or information...
Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: And of course inside your "res" directory is a "navigation" directory? and it contains  nav_graph.xml file, which when you double click loads correctly in the android IDE?

Comment: Is your `nav_graph.xml` really just empty? That won't work at all - you'd need to actually add a destination to it before you can use it. Please include it and the error message you're getting.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp , yes, there is this directory and it loads correctly on Ctrl+Left-Click

Comment: @ianhanniballake , the "code" for this xml is just the standart code - no destination or anything. Do I need to implement that? I have no experience with thode NavGraphs, but when I firstly have to do that, I know where to start.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/nav_graph">

</navigation>

Comment: The error message should specificially say you need a startDestination, so yes, you need to add one of those :) Sounds like going through the [Getting Started guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) or the [Navigation codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation) might be helpful.

Comment: @ianhanniballake so stupid of me... I did just read the inflating error, after that there is _no start destination defined via app:startDestination for com.example.{APPNAME}:id/nav_graph_ Thanks a lot! You can answer the post with this solution if you wish, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your navigation graph needs to have at least one destination - the start destination of your graph and the first screen users see when you inflate your graph as per the [Getting Started guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#Designate-start).

Answer (score 7):

After updating to 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0' I received the same error.

What worked for me was to change:

- in activity layout xml file from `<fragment` node to `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`

before

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
...
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

after

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
...
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

- in activity Class file how the `navController` is initialized

before

```
        navController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
```

after

```
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: this works. what is weird is that this only caused my app to fail sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

To navigation, you just need to implement two dependencies:

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version_navigation"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$version_navigation"
```

Please, share your nav_graph.xml

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggles with this problem can add this to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepnames class * extends android.os.Parcelable
-keepnames class * extends java.io.Serializable
```